# Determine text boundary box with Direct2D/DirectWrite

Tags: direct2d, directwrite

`ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawGlyphRun` takes the following params:

```
D2D1_POINT_2F baselineOrigin,
__in CONST DWRITE_GLYPH_RUN *glyphRun,
__in ID2D1Brush *foregroundBrush,
DWRITE_MEASURING_MODE measuringMode /*= DWRITE_MEASURING_MODE_NATURAL */
```

Where DWRITE_GLYPH_RUN is

```
struct DWRITE_GLYPH_RUN
{
    __notnull IDWriteFontFace* fontFace;
    FLOAT fontEmSize;
    UINT32 glyphCount;
    __field_ecount(glyphCount) UINT16 const* glyphIndices;
    __field_ecount_opt(glyphCount) FLOAT const* glyphAdvances;
    __field_ecount_opt(glyphCount) DWRITE_GLYPH_OFFSET const* glyphOffsets;
    BOOL isSideways;
    UINT32 bidiLevel;
};
```

I am trying to find out the smallest rect that contains the output glyphs.

This is all data I have. Note that I have 1 point which is `baselineOrigin` and I can potentially calculate the width using `glyphAdvances` and `glyphOffsets` from the `DWRITE_GLYPH_RUN`. The question is how to determine the height?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use an alternative way to do this before:

1. Create a path geometry
2. Open the path geometry to get the geometry sink
3. Call GetGlyphRunOutline to convert to text to geometry
4. Call GetBounds of the converted geometry to get the boundary rectangle

After converting the text to geometry, you can translate/rotate/scaling it, and do everything what a geometry can do. you can also just drop the geometry after getting the boundary rectangle and drawing with your own method.

Some codes for your references

```
// Create path geometry
hr = pD2DFactory->CreatePathGeometry(&pPathGeometry);
if(FAILED(hr))
{
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Create path geometry failed!", L"Error", 0);
        return;
}

// Open sink
hr = pPathGeometry->Open(&pGeometrySink);
if(FAILED(hr))
{
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Open geometry sink failed!", L"Error", 0);
        return;
}

// Get glyph run outline
hr = pFontFace->GetGlyphRunOutline(
        fontSize_,                              // font size
        pGlyphIndices,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        textLength,
        FALSE,
        FALSE,
        pGeometrySink
        );
if(FAILED(hr))
{
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Get glyph run outline failed!", L"Error", 0);
        return;
}

// Close sink
pGeometrySink->Close();
```

Comment: This method works almost perfectly but not quite. I get the boundaries, but they seems to be 1-2 pixels off in some areas. When I later render glyphs using produced geometry vs. using `DrawGlyphRun` using different color they don't exactly match. Any idea why would that be? I use all GetGlyphRunOutline parameters like this:
glyphRun->fontFace->GetGlyphRunOutline(
 glyphRun->fontEmSize,
 glyphRun->glyphIndices,
 glyphRun->glyphAdvances,
 glyphRun->glyphOffsets,
 glyphRun->glyphCount,
 glyphRun->isSideways,
 glyphRun->bidiLevel%2,
 pGeometrySink);
glyphRun is the same as passed to DrawGlyphRun.

Comment: I will look into this later.

Comment: @vt, boundaries don't have to match. When you do GetGlyphRunOutline() you basically force outline mode rendering, while DrawGlyphRun() is potentially bitmap renderer.