# How do I get the text extent when using ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawText

Tags: windows-8, directx, direct2d, directwrite

With Direct2D, I can use ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawText to draw text, but how can I get the text extent before I draw?  Note that I wish to do this under Windows 8 RT.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `Font.MeasureString` ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb296736%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) will help you out, but I've never tested it.

Comment: I think this can help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587532/determine-text-boundary-box-with-direct2d-directwrite

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the feedback.  I have found the solution.  I needed to create a IDWriteTextLayout for the text block and then call it's GetMetrics method which will return the extent of the text.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Yes, CreateTextLayout + GetMetrics yields the DWRITE_TEXT_METRICS::width and height field. Note that if you create an IDWriteTextLayout, you should then just pass that created IDWriteTextLayout to DrawTextLayout instead of calling DrawText again (which would unnecessarily need to lay out the text a second time).